# mysql nested cursor is already open

Tags: mysql, cursor, nested

I have a sp with two nested cursors. The outer cursor is customers, and the inner cursor is periods.
when an error occurs in the inner cursor I want to rollback what has been done for the specific customer and proceed with the processing of the next customer. However when the inner cursor is executed for the next customer (after an exception has occurred) I get an *"cursor is already open message"*

The code looks like this:

```
    DECLARE customers CURSOR FOR
    select * from customers_table;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_customers = 1;

    OPEN customers;

    customers_cursor:
    REPEAT
    FETCH customers
    INTO ....

    IF no_more_customers = 1
    THEN
        close customers;
        LEAVE customers_cursor;
    END IF;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
        rollback;
    END;

    ....... //do some stuff

    BEGIN
        DECLARE no_more_periods INT(1) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE periods CURSOR FOR
            SELECT ...

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET no_more_periods = 1;

        OPEN periods;

        periods_cursor:
        REPEAT
        FETCH periods INTO...

        IF no_more_periods = 1
        THEN
            close periods;
            LEAVE periods_cursor;
        END IF;

    ..... //do some stuff point 1

        UNTIL no_more_periods = 1
        END REPEAT periods_cursor;
        end;

    END;    

    UNTIL no_more_customers = 1
    END REPEAT customers_cursor;
END;
```

Customer 1 runs and and exception occurs in `//do some stuff point 1`. Then customer 2 runs until the `open periods` statement is reached and that's when I get the *"Cursor is already open"*.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: may be you need to close inner cursor when you catching exception

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any transactions or commits in your code. I would change the code to include the following:

- Start a new transaction for each customer
- Commit this transaction before starting on the next customer.
- Close the periods cursor before performing a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your help @JodyT .I am initiating a new block for each loop of the customer cursor (begin after the "if no_more_customer=1" block". Also i am doing "commit" before next customer. Unfortunately i cannot close periods cursor in the exception handler of this block (cursor periods not defined in this scope-compile time error).What i did to overcome the issue was to define an exception handler inside the inner loop  (exactly after the continue handler of the periods cursor).In this handler i close periods and then raise exception to perform rollback in the outter exception handler